# Removing the show method and all of its dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an existing entity that has been created by scaffolding. Now I'm realizing that I don't really need to present the **show** view and thus I'd like to eliminate any methods and pieces that are now unnecessary. Besides the `show` method created at the object controller for me, which other pieces should I remove? These are the ones I can think of:

- The `show.html.erb` file for the entity
- The `link_to` reference to the object instances at the `index.html.erb` and `edit.html.erb` files
- The `redirect_to` calls on the update and create methods at the controller

Is there anything else that I should remove?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should:

- Remove the `show` action from the controller
- Switch the `redirect_to`s in `create` and `update` to go to the new action
- Remove the `link_to`s from `index.html.erb` and `edit.html.erb`
- Remove the `app/views/entities/show.html.erb`
- Stop the routes from being generated by changing the `resources :entities` line in your *config/routes.rb* file to `resources :entities, :except => :show`

Answer (score 2):

You can/should remove:

- the show action in the controller
- the `show.html.erb` file
- the route to the show action (in routes.rb)
- any links or redirects to the show action

Comment: Wow, looks like we posted at the very same second. Tough luck :(

Comment: :) Maybe StackOverflow should show a "3 other users are drafting answers" popup...